# Ruby on Rails: include parameter in instance on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I'm currently doing a task at my work that can only be solved by altering an old code we have of an API. I have never used Ruby/Rails before yesterday so I'm facing some challenges to properly understand how to do it, but I believe it is pretty simple.

At the the controller file, I was able to create a new endpoint that returns all the information avaiable on our database via HTTP request. The request made by the user send two parameters: latitude and longitude, and the result obtained will be a list of places sorted by distance of each place from these coordinates. The code I'm using to do so is the following:

```
def myfunction
  @host = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
  
  # Filters
  @projects = Project.published

  # Coordinates and distance
  lat = geocode_params.fetch('latitude')
  lon = geocode_params.fetch('longitude')
  origin = Geokit::LatLng.new(lat, lon)
  distance_sql = Project.distance_sql(origin)
  
  # Getting closest places
  if (params[:latitude] != nil)
    ceil = params[:latitude].to_i + 1
    floor = params[:latitude].to_i - 1
    @projects = @projects.where('official_lat > ? AND official_lat < ?',floor,ceil)
  end

  if (params[:longitude] != nil)
    ceil = params[:longitude].to_i + 1
    floor = params[:longitude].to_i - 1
    @projects = @projects.where('official_long > ? AND official_long < ?',floor,ceil)
  end

  @projects = @projects.page(params[:page]).per(@items_perpage).order("#{distance_sql} ASC").limit(15)

  render json: @projects, meta: {count: @projects.total_count}, host: @host
end
```

I copied this "distance_sql" from another piece of code, but from my understanding it generates a new variable for each item in project with the distance in km between the place and the coordinates passed via the HTTP request.

I just wanted to include this distance on the parameters returned by the API. Since it is created "on-the-go", I couldn't find a way to include it on the serializer file.

I also tried to add this to the end of the code, but the endpoint stopped working:

```
  @projects = Project.includes(:distance_sql)
  render :json => @projects.to_json(:include => :distance_sql), meta: {count: @projects.total_count}, host: @host
```

Is it possible to do so?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: I thought "sql_distance" returned the distance in km because this API use to return all places within 50km, and in the controller code I found this:

`@projects_latlong = Project.published.within(50, origin: [lat, lon]).order("#{distance_sql} ASC").limit(MAX_PROJECTS_TO_SHOW)`

Which I assumed was the command to obtain the places within a 50km radius, but I'm not 100% sure of it. I also tried to look for "within" command in other files but to no success.

Comment: The data in that `meta` key is included in the response. You can see the docs here, it's provided by the `active_model_serializer` gem (see https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/active_model_serializers/0.9.0). However I'm not sure how you get the "distance" as a number to return ... it seems like it's a SQL query here

Comment: @max-pleaner I thought of including in the meta key, but the problem is that the "@projects" object is an array with all the places and their respective parameters, the meta key (i think) includes only information for the "whole", like the total count of items in "@projects". Since I needed the distance for each one, I discarded using the meta.
 The distance_sql is indeed a query, i thought it would return a number, but after your comment I noticed I might be wrong. I'll edit the question to clarify that

Comment: Yeah I think you need to find a way to distance sql query to return the distance for each record, once you do that, it shouldn't be that hard to return it from the JSON response. You might need to make it a virtual attribute on the model or something.

Answer (score 0):

If its possible I would use the [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) instead which does geospatial queries straight out of the box:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  geocoded_by :address
end
```

This lets you cut that entire mess down to:

```
@projects = Project.published.then do |scope|
  lat, lon = params[:latitude], params[:longitude]
  if lat.present? && lon.present?
    scope.near(lat, lon).order(distance: :asc)
  else 
    scope
  end
end.page(params[:page])
   .per(@items_perpage)
   .limit(15)
```